# Create VPN access to my house with Amazon?

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to create a VPN that could support multiple connections with TCP/IP using a VPN created in Amazon's cloud? I've been reading about http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/ but I keep getting the feeling that it's not creating a VPN bridge but rather an endpoint into the "cloud"

Ideally I'm looking to make my house the endpoint of the VPN and having upwards of 5 different locations connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the VPC is the endpoint for those connecting into it, but it can bridge to your physical network resources.

Another thing to look at is that connection to your house and how it's made.  Does your house make the connection to the VPC or does the VPC make the connection as needed.  Your ISP may block incoming VPN connections on residential accounts.